# How to create a catch all Apache VHOST entry?

Tags: apache-2.2, cname-record, virtualhost

Hi I'm trying to allow users to domain map to us using CNAME's. Our server is running CentOS 6.4 and Apache. When I create a CNAME on another domain we have with the values:

test.otherdomain.com -> app.example.com

The request loads www.example.com. This is the first rule in my VHOSTS which are ordered as follows;

```
:80
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
:443
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

:80
ServerName sub1.example.com
:443
ServerName sub1.example.com

:80
ServerName sub2.example.com
:443
ServerName sub2.example.com

:80
ServerName app.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
:443
ServerName app.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

The *.example.com is to allow users to create custom subdomains, so they can create anything that's not www, sub1, or sub2. Ex: acme.example.com.

After some research I gather the problem is the host being passed doesn't match any of my rules so the first defined site is being served? How can I create a default or catch all site that will serve app.example.com when a user visits test.otherdomain.com?

Users enter their domain in a form on our app so I can't add them all to my vhost entry as aliases. If I put app.example.com as the first rule (without wildcard alias) and again at the bottom of the file with the wildcard alias Apache seems to prefer the wildcard rule and the static subdomains sub1 and sub2 redirect to app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!

The first rule HAS to be the default. Changing rules like this made it work:

```
:80
ServerName app.example.com
:443
ServerName app.example.com

:80
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
:443
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

:80
ServerName sub1.example.com
:443
ServerName sub1.example.com

:80
ServerName sub2.example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
:443
ServerName sub2.doexampleain.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

This allows sub1 to be static, and since sub2/sub3 were only used to thread additional AJAX calls they were mini versions of the app. By moving that code into the main app and changing the wildcard so it's not part of the app rule everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Using Name-Based Virtual Hosting, the first VHOST entry defined in Apache is the catch-all entry for all hostnames that doesn't match anything else.

Since you mentioned you want the *app.example.com* VHOST to be served first, you should make sure it's the first one defined in your Apache config. There are multiple ways to achieve this:

- Adding it directly to the main config file
- Ensuring it's included first from the main config ([Include directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#include))
- If using an include dir, making the file listed first in alphabetical order such as by adding an underscore to the file name (ex. `_default.conf`)

Comment: Your second bullet point is correct, I posted my solution below but it won't let me upvote your reply?